# collect stats in teradata 14 - Multiple statistics with different column ordering on the same set of columns are not allowed

Tags: teradata

There is another gotcha with Teradata 14 (courtesy of TC) that may catch people out.

Using a table defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test( 
CALENDAR_DATE DATE FORMAT 'YY/MM/DD' NOT NULL           
,RETAIL_OUTLET_NUMBER INTEGER NOT NULL   
,BASE_PRODUCT_NUMBER INTEGER NOT NULL      
) 
PRIMARY INDEX (calendar_date, retail_outlet_number, base_product_number)
```

This SQL will fail:

```
COLLECT STATS test COLUMN(
calendar_date, base_product_number, retail_outlet_number);
```

with the error message:

> 3706: Syntax error: Multiple statistics with different column ordering on the same set of columns are not allowed

But:

```
COLLECT STATS test COLUMN(
calendar_date, retail_outlet_number, base_product_number);
```

will be OK.

The order of the columns must now be the same in the collect stats statement and the primary index.

...

Is there any other way to make them work with out changing the column order???

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Teradata 14 you can get around this problem for multi-column statistics by explicitly naming them:

```
COLLECT STATISTICS
 COLUMN (Calendar_Date, Base_Product_Number, Retail_Outlet_Number) AS Stats_CalDate_ProdNum_RtlNum
     ON test;
```

Subsequent recollections can be done using:

```
COLLECT STATISTICS COLUMN Stats_CalDate_ProdNum_RtlNum ON test;
```

There is an Orange Book available to Teradata customers through Teradata @ Your Service or your CSR that explains this and additional considerations for Teradata 14 Statistics. Carrie Ballinger has also written briefly about Teradata 14 Statistics enhancements [here](http://developer.teradata.com/blog/carrie/2012/08/new-opportunities-for-statistics-collection-in-teradata-14-0).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Rob. My Concern is, My logic is working fine in my own environment and also in staging. But when I put the same code in production, it is failing with the given error. Is it because of any Teradata environment settings?
The Data appliances for teradata are different for Production and Test.

Comment: What version of Teradata are you running in each environment?

Comment: I'm using Teradata 14 for both test and production.

Comment: If both environments are running Teradata 14 then I would expect to see Error 3706 if you do not use a named multi-column statistics collection on the same set of columns in a different order. Shouldn't have anything to do with environment settings. Is it possible the stats didn't exist in TEST when you collected them after getting the error in PROD.

Answer (score 2):

This error is coming because there are stats already collected in the order

> calendar_date, retail_outlet_number, base_product_number

You cannot collect stats on same columns in different orders. So if you want to collect in the order you desire i.e

> calendar_date, base_product_number, retail_outlet_number

You have to first DROP stats using

```
DROP STATS ON TEST COLUMN(calendar_date, retail_outlet_number, base_product_number);
```

and then collect again using your preferred order.